# ng-model value is not coming in date filter using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date, angular-filters

I am doing angular js search between from one date to another date using date picker .
I have made it ,every thing working fine .

But i am not getting the dynamic value of the date .which i have selected from the date picker .

I have passed two static date of given format its working fine.

I am not getting why it is not coming .

Below is the code.

```html
  <tr class="gradeU" ng-repeat="x in invoice| dateRange : from_date : to_date ">
```

This above one not working .
If i am using this one its working .

```html
  <tr class="gradeU" ng-repeat="x in invoice| dateRange : '2016-11-20' : '2016-11-25'">
```

Dont know why ,

i have passed it in ng-model also

```html
<div class="col-sm-2 m-b-xs">
    <input type="text"  name="from_date"  class="form-control"  placeholder="From" date-time view="date" auto-close="true" min-view="date" ng-model="from_date"  format="YYYY-MM-DD"   />
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 m-b-xs">
    <input type="text"  name="to_date" class="form-control"  placeholder="From" date-time view="date" auto-close="true" min-view="date" ng-model="to_date"  format="YYYY-MM-DD"   />
</div>
```

Can anybody suggest me,what is the error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check if `from_date` is of `date` type . Check the value of `from_date` in the page

Comment: @Raviteja I am not getting you

Comment: `dateRange` is a custom filter. Which types does it support? What's the type of `from_date`?

Comment: its type is text  @zeroflagL

Comment: Then make it of `date` type `new Date(from_date)` and give the format you want

Comment: Well, most datepickers create dates, not text. So that would explain why using values populated by the datepicker don't work in your example, **if** `dateRange` only supports text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `new Date(from_date)` to see if the variable contains a valid date

This will also convert the variable type into **Date** type if the variable contains a valid date as well

Comment: After using `new Date(from_date)` it does not show **Invalid Date** in console?